# Undocumented String.compareTo(null) NPE?

Tags: java, string, null, compareto

The following little test throws an NPE:

```
public class Test {

    public static void  main(String[] args) {

        String a = "a";
        String b = null;

        System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));

    }

}
```

Yet, the Javadoc of [compareTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) does not mention that the parameter cannot be `null`. This is strange, since Javadocs usually mentions when parameters cannot be `null`.

Is this just a glitch in the documentation or is there a more fundamental reason/twist I am missing?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get some explanation when you look at the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) interface:

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null)
>   should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns
>   false.

Comment: my pleasure. I was looking for a nice way to exceed the 3.6 k of reputation today. ;)